# Cannot find the error

Tags: sql-server

The code I have is

```
    SELECT     dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group], SUM(CASE WHEN RRDD NOT LIKE '12%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '13%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '16%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '17%' AND 
                      RRDD NOT LIKE '2706%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2707%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2331' THEN DUR_IN_HOURS ELSE 0 END) AS SP_DOM_HOURS, SUM(CASE WHEN RRDD NOT LIKE '12%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '13%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '16%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '17%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2706%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2707%' AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2331%' THEN CAST([2011 Total] AS FLOAT)*CASE WHEN IsNumeric([DUR_IN_HOURS]) =1 THEN CAST([DUR_IN_HOURS] AS FLOAT) ELSE 0 END)) AS SP_DOM_COST
FROM         dbo.COL_v_STD_REP_FullCourseDetail INNER JOIN
                      dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES ON dbo.COL_v_STD_REP_FullCourseDetail.Job_Group_Code = dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group Code] INNER JOIN
                      dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES_INTL ON dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group Code] = dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES_INTL.[Job Group Code]
```

The errors that arise Incorrect Syntax Near ')'

Comment: Any hints on the error(s)?

Comment: ...and the error message. And use carriage returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an `END` on the first `CASE`:

```
 SUM(CASE 
        WHEN RRDD NOT LIKE '12%' 
            AND RRDD NOT LIKE '13%' 
            AND RRDD NOT LIKE '16%' 
            AND RRDD NOT LIKE '17%' 
            AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2706%' 
            AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2707%' 
            AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2331%' 
        THEN CAST([2011 Total] AS FLOAT) 
      END -- this is missing
    *
    CASE 
        WHEN IsNumeric([DUR_IN_HOURS]) =1 
        THEN CAST([DUR_IN_HOURS] AS FLOAT) 
        ELSE 0 END) AS SP_DOM_COST
```

Your full query would be:

```
SELECT dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group], 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN RRDD NOT LIKE '12%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '13%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '16%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '17%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2706%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2707%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2331' 
            THEN DUR_IN_HOURS 
            ELSE 0 END) AS SP_DOM_HOURS, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN RRDD NOT LIKE '12%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '13%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '16%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '17%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2706%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2707%' 
                AND RRDD NOT LIKE '2331%' 
            THEN CAST([2011 Total] AS FLOAT) END
        *
        CASE 
            WHEN IsNumeric([DUR_IN_HOURS]) =1 
            THEN CAST([DUR_IN_HOURS] AS FLOAT) 
            ELSE 0 END) AS SP_DOM_COST
FROM  dbo.COL_v_STD_REP_FullCourseDetail 
INNER JOIN dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES 
    ON dbo.COL_v_STD_REP_FullCourseDetail.Job_Group_Code = dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group Code] 
INNER JOIN dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES_INTL 
    ON dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group Code] = dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES_INTL.[Job Group Code]
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: @Andrew see my edit, there was an extra parentheses